# how to fix directory for import?

Tags: discord.py

so basically i am trying a change prefix command and  i want to fix the directory
i am trying to do `import cogs.json`  in this
[file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R91vX.png)

I realize that i get the error`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cogs'` because of the directory of files but i dont know how to fix the directory to go there
can anyone help?
`i am trying to go to the _json.py inside of the cogs folder, besides that i might try just moving the _json file into the bot folder if that might work

Comment: Check the directory of your site-packages and move it there. `python -m site` Seems like you didnt install this with pip?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
from cogs import _json
```

also, if you want you can rename your local name for the package

```
from cogs import _json as jsonModule
```

if this doesn't work, try

```
from ..cogs import _json
```

For more help, please look at this https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html